# Get primary table entries where the latest secondary entry was 6 months ago

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

```
I have two tables 1- `FormTemplate` where the columns are Id, CreatedDate, Creator, Schema and 2 - `FormSubmissions` where the columns are Id, FormTemplateId(Foreign key), Created Date, Creator.

FormTemplate

| Id         | CreatedDate            | Creator | Schema  |
|------------|------------------------|---------|---------|
|          1 | 2023-01-25 00:52:43.717| John    | {}      |
|          2 | 2023-01-25 00:52:43.717| Same    | {}      |
|          3 | 2023-01-25 00:52:43.717| Alee    | {}      |

FormSubmission

| Id     | FormTemplateId (Foreign key)|  CreatedDate           |   Creator  | 
|--------|-----------------------------|------------------------|------------|
|      1 |                            2| 2023-05-25 00:52:43.717|       Kyle |
|      2 |                            2| 2023-02-25 00:52:43.717|      Kayla |
|      3 |                            3| 2019-03-08 00:52:43.717|     Arthur |
|      4 |                            3| 2019-02-25 00:52:43.717|      Milli |
```

I would like to get all `FormTemplate` rows where the LATEST `FormSubmission` was 6 months ago. in the above table: I should get only the 3rd row (Id=3) from `FormTemplate`

I cannot create a query or find a way to fetch FormTemplates with this criteria efficiently.

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: @ThomA I am using this on an Azure SQL database. Edited to add the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a pre-grouped join.

```sql
SELECT
  t.*,
  s.*
FROM FormTemplate t
JOIN (
    SELECT
      s.FormTemplateId,
      MaxCreated = MAX(s.CreatedDate)
    FROM FormSubmission s
    GROUP BY s.FormTemplateId
    HAVING MAX(s.CreatedDate) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
) s ON t.ID = s.FormTemplateId;
```

To get the actual ID of the subquery, you can instead use an `APPLY` subquery with a `TOP 1`

```sql
SELECT
  t.*,
  s.*
FROM FormTemplate t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      s.FormTemplateId,
      s.CreatedDate
    FROM FormSubmission s
    WHERE t.ID = s.FormTemplateId
    ORDER BY s.CreatedDate DESC
) s
WHERE s.CreatedDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE());
```

As far as the other answers are concerned, as long as you are grouping by `t.ID` the performance will almost certainly be the same.

Comment: I am running your query but would want to get the FormSubmission.Id in the result which is not showing atm with the above. I am getting `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` 

I would like to know which FormSubmission is the latest entry (submitted more than 6 months ago)

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FormTemplate;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FormSubmission;

CREATE TABLE #FormTemplate 
(
Id          INT          NOT NULL,
CreatedDate datetime     NOT NULL,
Creator     varchar(50)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #FormTemplate
VALUES
  (1, '2023-01-25 00:52:43.717', 'John')
, (2, '2023-01-25 00:52:43.717', 'Same')
, (3, '2023-01-25 00:52:43.717', 'Alee')
;

CREATE TABLE #FormSubmission 
(
Id             INT         NOT NULL,
FormTemplateId INT         NOT NULL,
CreatedDate    datetime    NOT NULL,
Creator        varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #FormSubmission 
VALUES
  (1, 2, '2023-05-25 00:52:43.717', 'Kyle')
, (2, 2, '2023-02-25 00:52:43.717', 'Kayla')
, (3, 3, '2019-03-08 00:52:43.717', 'Arthur')
, (4, 3, '2019-02-25 00:52:43.717', 'Milli')
;

SELECT T.Id, MAX(T.CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate, T.Creator
FROM #FormTemplate AS T
INNER JOIN #FormSubmission AS S
ON  T.ID = S.FormTemplateId
GROUP BY T.Id, T.Creator
HAVING MAX(S.CreatedDate) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select FormTemplateId
into #old
from FormSubmission
group by FormTemplateId
having max(CreatedDate)<=dateadd(month,-6,getdate())

select * from FormTemplate where Id in (select FormTemplateId from #old)
```

Comment: does it also delete #old after query?

Comment: #tables die automatically at the end of the session